# Validating set up and tear down before and after running tests in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have some resource creation and deletion code that needs to run before and after certain tests, which I've put into a fixture using `yield` in the usual way.  However, before running the tests, I want to verify that the resource creation has happened correctly, and likewise after the deletion, I want to verify that it has happened.  I can easily stick asserts into the fixtures themselves, but I'm not sure this is good pytest practice, and I'm concerned that it will make debugging and interpreting the logs harder.  Is there a better or canonical way to do validation in pytest?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered something like this recently - although, I was using unittest instead of pytest.

What I ended up doing was something similar to a [`method level setup/teardown`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown). That way, future test functions would never be affected by past test functions.

For my use-case, I loaded my test fixtures in this setup function, then ran a couple of basic tests against those tests to ensure validity of fixtures (as part of setup itself). This, I realized, added a bit of time to each test in the class, but ensured that all the fixture data was exactly what I expected it to be (we were loading stuff into a dockerized elasticsearch container). I guess time for running tests is something you can make a judgement call about.